# CocoaPods not creating Pods.xcconfig on pod install

Tags: ios, ruby, cocoapods

CocoaPods is no longer creating a `Pods.xcconfig` file automatically on `pod install` for my project. The file is shown in red font within the project workspace and is not in the `Pods/` directory.

My `Podfile` looks like this:

```
platform :ios, '7.0'

target "ProjectName" do

    # Team Created Pods - kept and versioned in private spec repo
    pod 'ProjectImageObject', '0.1.0'
    pod 'Image+Bundle+Name', '0.1.0'

    # Team Forked Pods - kept and versioned in private spec Repo
    pod 'MagicalRecord', '2.2.1-pn'

    pod 'KeychainItemWrapper', '0.1.0'
    pod 'DCRoundSwitch', '0.1.0'
    pod 'JBSignatureController', '0.1.0'
    pod 'MBProgressHUD', '0.5.1-pn'
    pod 'PKRevealController', '1.1.0-pn'
    pod 'SMCalloutView', '2.0'
    pod 'SVPullToRefresh', '0.4.2-pn'
    pod 'TimesSquare', '1.1.0-pn'
    pod 'XMLReader', '0.1.0'

    # Third-Party Pods
    pod 'Reachability', '~> 3.1.1'
    pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.1'
    pod 'TTTAttributedLabel', '~>1.8'
    pod 'TPKeyboardAvoiding', '~> 1.2.3'
end

target "ProjectNameTests" do

    # Team Created Pods - kept and versioned in private spec rep
    pod 'SharedTestCore'

    # Third-Party Pods
    pod 'OCHamcrest', '~> 3.0.1'
    pod 'OCMockito', '~> 1.1.0'
end
```

When I run `pod install` via Terminal, no error is thrown. Strangely enough, `Pods-ProjectName.xcconfig` is created.

What do I need to do to fix `CocoaPods` to automatically create the `Pods.xcconfig` file?

**What I've tried so far :**

- Running `pod install` again.
- Deleting `Pods/` directory, `Podfile.lock`, the project `workspace`, and running `pod install`
- Verifying that all `search paths` are default values (CocoaPods help guide mentions this can cause problems otherwise?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Originally, I didn't specify the `target "ProjectName"` wrapper in my `Podfile`. Instead, I simply had

```
# Team Created Pods - kept and versioned in private spec repo
pod 'ProjectImageObject', '0.1.0'
pod 'Image+Bundle+Name', '0.1.0'

# Team Forked Pods - kept and versioned in private spec Repo
pod 'MagicalRecord', '2.2.1-pn'
# ... and so on ...
```

Hence, `Pods.xcconfig` (for the `universal` pod list) was created and `libPods.a` was added to the `Link binary with library` build stage of my `ProjectName` target.

Later, I wrapped said block in `target "ProjectName" do`, i.e.

```
target "ProjectName" do

    # Team Created Pods - kept and versioned in private spec repo
    pod 'ProjectImageObject', '0.1.0'
    pod 'Image+Bundle+Name', '0.1.0'

    # Team Forked Pods - kept and versioned in private spec Repo
    pod 'MagicalRecord', '2.2.1-pn'
    # ... and so on...
end
```

This created a `Pods-ProjectName.xcconfig`, but it did **not** create `Pods.xcconfig` (as no files belonged to the `default` pod list) or `libPod.a`.

CocoaPods also did **not** remove `libPods.a` from the `Link binary with library` build stage or `Pods.xcconfig` from the workspace.

This resulted in linker errors to the effect of `libPods.a can not be found`.

To fix it, I reverted to the original target-less `pod` statements (my `ProjectNameTest` target needs to see these pods too) and had to manually remove `libPods.a` from the `Link binary with library` build stage and `Pods.xcconfig` from the workspace.

Ideally, CocoaPods would take care of this clean up for you, and hopefully, this will be the case in the future (current version of CocoaPods as of this writing is 0.29, which requires this manual cleanup process).